# Gitignore: Ignore everything in folder except some files. Ignore everything in subfolder of the same folder except some files

Tags: git, gitignore

I am trying to solve this problem in my `.gitignore`.

```
# Ignore lightning_logs
**/models/lightning_logs/*
# Except the following
!**/models/lightning_logs/version_k

# Ignore models
**/models/*
# Except the following
!**/models/saved_model.ckpt
```

However, this does not work because the line `**/models/*` ignores `version_k`.

Alternatively, the following does not work:

```
# Ignore models
**/models/*
# Except the following
!**/models/lightning_logs/version_k
!**/models/saved_model.ckpt
```

Because the line `**/models/*` prevents indexing of subfolders, so `lightning_logs` is never indexed by git and `version_k` is once again ignored.

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired result you have to tell it to track `lightning_logs` - but exclude the content. It's a bit convoluted - but this should work for you

```
# Ignore models
**/models/**/*
# Except this one
!**/models/saved_model.ckpt
# Don't ignore the folder
!**/models/lightning_logs
# but ignore the contents
**/models/lightning_logs/*
# Except the following
!**/models/lightning_logs/version_k
```